Authenticating Azure AD client credential tokens using certificate/public key
I am fetching a client credential token from token endpoint of azure - https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
After this, I match the "kid" from token and kids available in https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/discovery/v2.0/keys
and use the value in x5c as certificate to validate the token, but it is giving a error as
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA

I am using "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" as scope to fetch token, but still not working
Validation of Azure AD token signature is invalid. The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA

You cannot validate the access token which contains aud as Microsoft Graph that is https://graph.microsoft.com as it is not meant for the application.

Any update on the issue?


Note that: You cannot validate the access token which contains aud as Microsoft Graph that is https://graph.microsoft.com  or 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 .


Only the access tokens meant for the application must be validated.
Microsoft Graph access token is intended to be used with Microsoft services.

Initially I generated access token by passing scope as https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id : ClientID
scope : https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret : ClientSecret
grant_type : client_credentials


When decoded I got Invalid Signature error:

Hence you can make use of Microsoft Graph API access token directly without validating it.
You can validate the token meant for the application like below:
I exposed an API, created app role and added API permissions:

Now I generated token by passing scope as api//ClientID/.default

The signature is verified successfully:

